# Seting up a webhook to track Voximplant's scenario status with all its data

Tags: voximplant

I'm writing an application on Voximplant platform and I want to set up a webhook to track Voximplant's scenario status with all its data. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it easily via the following API request: https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/net/httprequest